# Two sign_in forms each on own url in rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Its possible to create 2 sign in views / 2 forms each on own urls in DEVISE ? 
I need one for web administrator (back administration) and one for users (application), 1 model (with roles)

1. web administration / admin.domain.tld/login
2. user application / app.domain.tld/login

(after unsucessful sign in must stay on some url admin on admin.domain.tld/login
, and user on app.domain.tld/login)

is this possible ? how to do it ?

Comment: Why don't you just create a `User` model and an `Admin` model? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role

Comment: @n_i_c_k why to have two models, when all can be in one with different roles ? im searching solution with one model (if its possible)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have it

controllers/admin/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

controllers/app/sessions_controller.rb

```
class App::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

views/admin/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, url: admin_login_path) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
      <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

views/app/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, url: app_login_path) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
      <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
  namespace :app do
    devise_for :users

    devise_scope :app_user do
      get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
      post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
    end
  end

  namespace :admin do
    devise_for :users

    devise_scope :admin_user do
      get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
      post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
    end
  end
```

all works fine, also possible add `:constraints => {:host => "domain"}` and edit routes to desired url's

Comment: you seem to be declaring two different scopes, what means that both an admin user and a app_user can be logged in at the same time. Is that the intended behaviour?